# If we "delete" the term of norm in SVR problem formulation, can it be solved with simplex method?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, optimization, linear-programming

The problem formulation in Support Vector Regression is,

[image]

What if we don't want to take the "flatness" term, i.e., $\frac 1 2 ||w||^2$ and delete it; can we find solution from simplex method for linear programming, i.e. is it solvable? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this becomes a linear programming problem. Of course, there are good reasons for including the term to prevent overfitting.

Comment: What are the reasons? I still don't understand the relationship between the term and overfitting. Thank you